# Allow only 1 character in TextBox

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, textbox, code-snippets

I've coded a generic snippet to allow only 1 character in a TextBox in several ways, the code works pretty good but the thing is the code size has been quite extensive so I want to know suggestions or modifications if the code can be simplified:

```
#Region " [TextBox] Allow only 1 Character "


' By Elektro H@cker


' TextBox [Enter]
Private Sub TextBox_Enter(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) ' Handles TextBox1.MouseEnter

    ' Allign the character in the TextBox space
    ' If Not TextBox_Separator.TextAlign = HorizontalAlignment.Center Then TextBox_Separator.TextAlign = HorizontalAlignment.Center Then

    ' Disable Copy/Paste contextmenu by creating a new one
    If sender.ContextMenuStrip Is Nothing Then sender.ContextMenuStrip = New ContextMenuStrip

End Sub

' TextBox [KeyPress]
Private Sub TextBox_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) ' Handles TextBox1.KeyPress

    Select Case sender.TextLength

        Case 0 ' TextLength = 0

            Select Case e.KeyChar

                Case Chr(22) ' CTRL+V is pressed

                    ' If Clipboard contains 0 or 1 character then paste the character.
                    e.Handled = IIf(Clipboard.GetText.Length <= 1, False, True)

                Case Else ' Other key is pressed
                    e.Handled = False ' Print the character.

            End Select ' e.KeyChar when TextLength = 0

        Case 1 ' TextLength = 1

            Select Case e.KeyChar

                Case Convert.ToChar(Keys.Back) ' Backspace is pressed
                    e.Handled = False ' Delete the character

                Case Chr(22) ' CTRL+V is pressed

                    Select Case sender.SelectionLength

                        Case 1 ' If 1 character is selected
                            ' If Clipboard contains 0 or 1 character then paste the character.
                            e.Handled = IIf(Clipboard.GetText.Length <= 1, False, True)

                        Case Else ' If any text is selected
                            e.Handled = True ' Don't paste the characters.

                    End Select

                Case Else ' Other key is pressed
                    ' If any text is selected then don't print the character.
                    e.Handled = IIf(sender.SelectionLength = 1, False, True)

            End Select ' e.KeyChar when TextLength = 1

    End Select ' TextLength

End Sub

#End Region
```

Comment: whats wrong with `.MaxLength = 1`?

Comment: The thing Is I wrote the code 'cause I don't wanted to use the logic of maxlenght property because when a word is copied from clipboard then the first character of the word is pasted, my code paste the word only if wordlength is equals to 1 otherway don't paste any character, sorry for my english

Comment: sounds like a nice touch, but it is not your fault that it works like that.  its not like user will not have encountered it before and know why

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is very simple to do. You have over complicated the code.

```
TextBox1.MaxLength = 1
```

You can even do it in the properties window.

Comment: Thanks, Really using the MaxLength prop is not what I need but maybe I'm making a mountain out of a molehill

Comment: and for validation use the textchanged event

Answer (score 1):

Fix the length of textbox....

```
 <asp:TextBox ID="txt_enter" runat="server" MaxLength="1"></TextBox>
```